# project like google keep, but when i click on single delete it deletes everything

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

```js
var btn1=document.querySelector(".btn");
const remover=( text ='')=>{
    var note=document.createElement("div");
    note.classList.add('note')
    const htmldata=`
    
    <div class="operations">
          <button class="btn1">  <i class="fas fa-edit "></i></button>
           <button id="btn2"> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt">delete</i></button>
            
        </div>
        <textarea ></textarea> 
    
    `
    note.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",htmldata)
    document.body.appendChild(note)

    var deletebtn=document.querySelector("#btn2")
    deletebtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        note.remove()
    })
}



btn1.addEventListener("click",remover)
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
      <i class="far fa-sticky-note fa-5x"></i>
      <p id="headertext">Adoo Notes</p>
    </header>
    <section>
      <button class="btn">Add Note</button>
    </section>

    <!-- <div class="note">
         
    </div>  -->
    <script src="index.js"></script>
```

NOTE: I am not so good at English.

when I click on add note so note appears but if there is more than one note when I click on delete so it is not deleting it if I click on the first note delete so all the notes are deleted. I want when I click on delete so only one note delete at a time

Comment: Your add function itself is called `remover`. That in itself is a red flag. Separate add and remove functionally

Comment: Can you please explain what i need to do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the delete button within the note you created like:

```
var deletebtn = note.querySelector("#btn2")
```

Following code will alwayds.return the first match, which is first delete button. On that note `id` should ne unique so you should change it to a class.

```
document.querySelector("#btn2")
```

```js
var btn1 = document.querySelector(".btn");
const remover = (text = '') => {
  var note = document.createElement("div");
  note.classList.add('note')
  const htmldata = `
    
    <div class="operations">
          <button class="btn1">  <i class="fas fa-edit "></i></button>
           <button id="btn2"> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt">delete</i></button>
            
        </div>
        <textarea ></textarea> 
    
    `
  note.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", htmldata)
  document.body.appendChild(note)

  var deletebtn = note.querySelector("#btn2")
  deletebtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    note.remove()
  })
}



btn1.addEventListener("click", remover)
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <i class="far fa-sticky-note fa-5x"></i>
    <p id="headertext">Adoo Notes</p>
  </header>
  <section>
    <button class="btn">Add Note</button>
  </section>

  <!-- <div class="note">
         
    </div>  -->
  <script src="index.js"></script>
```